# Symbol-level frequency-selective channel model representation (in OFDM)

Tags: wireless, ofdm

The general symbol-level representation for a frequency-selective channel is:

$$
y[k] = \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} s[k-l]h_{l} + z[k]
$$

where \$s[k-l]\$ is transmitted symbols, \$z[k]\$ is noise, \$L\$ is the channel length. Here \$h_l\$ only have values when \$l\$ is nonnegative, it's reasonable since the channel is causal (\$y[k]\$ depends only on \$a[k]\$, \$a[k-1]\$,...), but when I read Tse's book, it shows the sample-level channel representation:

$$
 h_m = \sum_{i} a_i sinc[m-\tau_i W]
$$

where \$a_i, \tau_i\$ means the strength and delay at i th path, \$W\$ means the bandwidth. It's clear that \$h_m\$ can have values in negative parts, so I wonder what's the relationship between the \$h_l\$ in the first equation and \$h_m\$ in the second equation? (i.e. how can we deal with the \$h_m\$ when \$m < 0\$ in the second equation?)

Comment: use a negative integer delay in the sinc and determine the sinc's value.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what do you mean by negative integer delay? \$\tau_i W\$ should always be non-negative, right? You mean just take negative \$m\$ into the equation and treat the \$h_m\$ sequences like \$h_l\$? I saw some codes do this, but what is the reason for that? I think I definitely missed some important points when getting from \$h_m\$ to \$h_l\$

Comment: the sinc is just how we model sampling; what I was trying to hint at is the periodic 0 points it has in all the other sampling points. You only "see" one non-zero sinc value after sampling, so causality has no problems with this.